# How to get celery results model (using django-celery-results) within task

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm planning on using `django-celery-results` backend to track status and results of Celery tasks.

Is the `django-celery-results` backend suitable to store status of task while it is running, or only after it has finished?

It's not clear when the `TaskResult` model is first created (upon task creation, task execution, or completion?)

If it's created upon task creation, will the model status automatically be updated to RUNNING when the task is picked up, if `task_track_started` option is set?

Can the `TaskResult` instance be accessed within the task function?

Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947445/is-it-possible-to-query-state-of-a-celery-tasks-using-django-celery-results-duri) appears to indicate so but doesn't mention task status update to RUNNING

Answer (score 4):

About Taskresult, of course, you can access during execution task, you only need import:

```py
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
```

With this you can access to model taskresult filter by task_id, task_name etc,
This is official code, you can filter by any of this fields https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/blob/master/django_celery_results/models.py

Example:

```py
shared_task(bind=True, name='My custom name for task')
def populate_category_tree(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # * self is a representation from app.Task
    task_result = TaskResult.objects.get_task(self.request.id) 
    task_result.status='RUNNING'
    task_result.save()
```

In addition, you can add some additional data necessaries for your task in models fields. When task is created and is in execution also is posible modify fields but in case that status is 'SUCCEES', you only can read it, status task is auto save by default.

Example:

```py
task_result.meta = json.dumps({'help_text': {'date': '2020-11-30'}})
```

I recommend work with `as_dict()` function, here you can watch models attributes.

Comment: Thanks, it's still not clear exactly when the TaskResult instance for a task is first created, and when its status is updated automatically during lifecycle

Comment: Yes, when you use `bind=True` as a parameter in the decorator for yout function task, you can define a `self`` param as a first argument in the function, this self param is like a instance of the task where you can control custom states and modify value fields in the model TaskResult

Comment: I believe that in this case the 'self' parameter will refer to the Task object (as received from the broker), not the TaskResult model which is just used to store the results of a completed task using the django-celery-results backend

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right I am sorry for my confusion, in the following comment I detail how to access the TaskResult and change its status

Answer (score 0):

Backend is configured in settings module as:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db' # in this case it is django DB
```

If you configured django DB as a backend then you could import it as

```
from django-celery-results.models import TaskResult
```

Comment: This doesnt explain the TaskResult instance creation and lifecycle information I'm after